# sum sub totals of repeated items with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to calculate the total of repeat items in a table with angular. I'm able to sum up getting the sub total per each item but getting the grand sum of all the items is the problem

```
.controller('reciept_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$state','$stateParams','$window',function($scope,$http,$state,$stateParams,$window){
    $scope.shop_id=localStorage.getItem("shop_id");
    $scope.payment_id=localStorage.getItem("payment_id");
    $http.get('http://localhost/sales/reciept.php?payment_id='+$stateParams.payment_id + "&shop_id="+$scope.shop_id).success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.reciept=data;

       });
```

HTML

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in reciept">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
          <tr>
            <td width="50%"><div align="left">{{item.item}}</div></td>
            <td width="16%"><div align="center">{{item.price}}</div></td>
            <td width="12%"><div align="center">{{item.quantity}}</div></td>
            <td width="20%"><div align="center">GH¢ {{item.quantity*item.price}}</div></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>

       </div>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Grand Total:</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is there any necessary that you would HAVE to calculate the size in markup instead of JS?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function to calculate the grand total,

```
 $scope.getTotal = function(type) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(el) {
            total += el[type];
        });
        return total;
    };
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3EB4tI2rro0SaKn2gO2A?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the total value like

```
<td width="16%" ng-init="total=total+item.price"><div align="center">{{item.price}}</div></td>
```

and in your grand total just put

```
<td>Grand Total:{{total}}</td>
```